# Push changes to Github from Jenkins Job

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to push changes to a git repo from Jenkins and unfortunately have run out of options.

I've tried:

`withCredentials([UsernamePassword(credentialsId: 'github', gitToolName: 'git-tool')])`

Also tried using the custom app integration that I have configured but that only seems to work for HTTPS which prevents me from pushing to github..

If I use the custom app integration I get: `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address`

If I use `withCredentials` I get: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'UsernamePassword' found among steps`

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: If I use Git Hub App integration, I get `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address` if I use the above solution I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'UsernamePassword' found among steps`

Comment: [edit] the question to include that